# Parse Android - custom push notification with JSON

Tags: android, json, push-notification, parse-platform

I want send push notification with parameter.

- I Create a custom BroadcastReceiver and I declared it in my AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <receiver android:name="com.myapp.receiver.MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.myapp.CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```

  Now if I send JSON notification by Parse.com whit key *action* and value *com.myapp.CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION* my BroadcastReceiver catch notification.
  sample JSON :

  ```
  {
     "action":"com.myapp.CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION",
     "alert":"My custom title",
     "thingid":"123456789"
  }
  ```
- I replace : `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyFirstActivity.class);` to `PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);` for a JSON with the key *alert* is not processed by the default Parse BroadcastReceiver and avoid receiving notification twice.
- But now my application no longer receives the notification by Parse.com just with text.

The only solution I see is to completely replace the default BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.myapp.receiver.MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But I have Parse error and I don't know Parse supports REGISTRATION.

Can I do just remplace *com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver* ?

Thanks